# Word VBA to remove all except first character of every selected word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Apologies if this has been previously asked, but while somewhat similar problems have been addresses I've not been able to find a working solution to this specific question.

Using VBA in Microsoft Word (currently using 365/16), how can I efficiently remove all but the first character of each word that is currently selected? If it is more simple to assume that all words are wrapped by one space on both sides that is acceptable knowing it would leave words starting and ending sentences, as well as (most commonly) words followed by a comma. I also need the solution to leave all existing formatting in place (including section and page layout, etc.), especially the case sensitivity of the first letter after removing the remaining letters. An example would be:

---

#### Original

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at Risus Viverra adipiscing. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque.

Lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id Interdum Velit 23 Laoreet. Et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor.

#### Becoming

L i d s a, c a e, s d e t i u l e d m a. T d c a e t a R V a. P s a p e d m. U p o n p.

L m a u p l a. U d c c t i I V 2 L. E l d u d q n p.

---

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a macro/VBA for that - a simple *wildcard* Find/Replace will do, where:

```
Find = (<[! ])*>
Replace = \1
```